# Move object with mouse cursor - Java

Tags: java, performance, swing, graphics2d

I have to do the Agario game using object oriented programming with Java. So far I've draw a circle and I was able to make it follow my cursor. However I have many bugs like the ball not following the cursor after the cursor touches the ball, sometimes, the ball moves to quickly, other times it moves to slowly.

Overall I think it's far from perfect and would like some suggestions. I just have to make it follow and I'm struggling a bit. Here's the code:

window class:

```
public class window extends JFrame implements Runnable {

  Ball b = new Ball();
  Thread t = new Thread(this);

  public window () {
    setSize(600, 600);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
    t.start();

    addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
        public void mouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            formMouseMoved(evt);
        }

    });

  }

  private void formMouseMoved(MouseEvent evt) {
    b.setnewtarget(evt.getX(), evt.getY());
  }

  @Override
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    b.drawCenteredCircle(g);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new window ();
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
        repaint();
    }
  }
```

}

Here´s the Ball class:

```
public class Ball implements Runnable {

  Thread t = new Thread(this);
  int x, y, r;
  int targetx, targety;

  public Ball() {
    x = 300;
    y = 300;
    r = 35;
    t.start();
  }

  public void drawCenteredCircle(Graphics g) {
    g.fillOval(x, y, r, r);
    g.drawLine(x, y, targetx, targety);
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (true) 

         int dx = Math.abs(targetx-x);
         int dy = Math.abs(targety-x);

         if (dx > dy) {
            int oldx = x;
            if (x > targetx)
               x--;
            else
               x++;

            y =((targety-y)/(targetx-x))*(x-oldx)+y;
         } else {
            int oldy = y;
            if (y > targety)
               y--;
            else
               y++;

            x =((targetx-x)/(targety-y))*(y-oldy)+x;
         }

        try {
            t.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Bola.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
  }

  void setnewtarget(int x, int y) {
    targetx = x;
    targety = y;
  }
}
```

Thanks :D

Comment: Stackoverflow is more fit for question dealing with a specific problem. Your question and call for suggestions, as it is phrased, is too broad.

Comment: @k0pernikus I've post my question on codereview.stackexchange.com . Thanks for taking your time to reply to my question. About my problem, I just can't think of a better code to follow the ball with my cursor :(

Comment: @RicardoReis definitely not on-topic on Code Review though. We don't fix code.

Comment: The problem about how the ball is not following your cursoe is valid here! Just phrase it more concise to only be about that problem and don't hesitate to ask multiple question for different problems even if they share similar code base. For further reference read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Unlike seemingly every single NPC in the first few zones of Pokémon, here at CR we are not Bug Trainers, so this question would be inappropriate for migration or x-posting

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no need for the Thread. You should NOT be using the infinite while loop. Get rid of that code
2. In the `formMouseMoved(...)` moved method you invoked repaint() which will cause the component to paint itself.
3. Also, get rid of the Thread and while loop in your Ball class.

The key point is that Swing is event driven. The `mouseMoved(...)` event is all you need for the animation. Every time you drag the mouse an event will be generated which will cause you to repaint the Ball.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'll remove the Thread! Every time I would use graphics without repaint, the app when minimized and maximize would make the draw disappear, I'll follow your suggestions. Thanks

Comment: `Every time I would use graphics without repaint, the app when minimized and maximize would make the draw disappear`. I suggest you start with the working example found in the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html). It will show you a better way to do painting. That is you should be extending `paintComponent(...) of a JPanel and paint the Ball and then you add the panel to the frame. The example just changes the location each time you click so I suggest you first change the example to change the location on a mouseMove().